# @ionic-native/file/ngx TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: android, file, properties, undefined, native

I-ve already install the native-s file plugin in both places, my app.module.ts and the service.ts itself (import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';). I've also added to my providers' list. However, when the real android device tries to do the following command

```
      this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, this.recordsFile)
                .then( exists => {
                  console.log('File exists?', exists);
                  return this.writeToFile(text);
                })
```

Yields: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

This works perfectly when running through the USB port (ionic cordova run android -l --host=###.###.###.###)

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.1 (C:\Users\emili\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.4.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1002.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.2.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : 6.0.0, android 9.0.0, browser, ios 6.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.2
   native-run  : 1.2.2

System:

   NodeJS : v12.19.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.8
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. Best regards,

Emiliano

Comment: I gathered the problem is that this.file.dataDirectory is answering null. Any ideas how to get that right? Thanks in advance. Best regards, Emiliano

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. This had been working for a while now. Not sure what has broken it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did anyone found the solution?